# How do I get information from Visual Studio PerfWatson?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

My Visual Studio 2010 pro, which I use for programming C#, has suddenly slowed to a crawl. I get "Not Responding" a lot!

I have installed Visual Studio PerfWatson and it seems like it does its thing. It creates a number of .dmp and .maxdelay files.

So Microsoft gets information about what's going on, but how do I get this information?

// Anders

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, PerfWatson is not really built for end-user troubleshooting. When it detects a delayed response from a UI element or whatever it gathers as much information as it can and then tries to send it to MS; you should see a prompt when this happens and most of the information is available there (or in the generated dmp files which you should be able to open with any decent text editor).

If you want to dig around and find the cause of the issue yourself, I would typically recommend something like Process Monitor

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

When VS freezes you should be able to look at all sorts of interesting data with Process Monitor including individual operations and their results, the call stack, etc.

Comment: I have now tested by using Process Monitor and it looks kind of strange! devenv.exe is accessing the file system continuously for all files that is open in the text editor. Could someone please use Process Monitor and see if their VS2010 also access files continuously?